# 'XcvData' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to install a virtual printer with Ghostscript and RedMon which prints to a PDF file using c++, but when i try to compile my code, i got `'XcvData' was not declared in this scope` on the function below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winspool.h>
BOOL AddPort()
{
    DWORD cbneed,cbstate;
    PBYTE pOutputData;
    HANDLE hXcv = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PRINTER_DEFAULTS Defaults = { NULL,NULL,SERVER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER };

    WCHAR pszPortName[]=L"UTReportPDFPort:";
    pOutputData=(PBYTE)malloc(MAX_PATH);

    if(!OpenPrinter((WCHAR*)",XcvMonitor Redirected Port",&hXcv,&Defaults ))
    {
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        GetLastError();
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), NULL,(LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL );
        ::MessageBox(0,(LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf,(WCHAR*)"ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        free(pOutputData);
        LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );
        return FALSE;

    }
    if(!XcvData(hXcv,L"AddPort",(PBYTE)pszPortName,sizeof(pszPortName),(PBYTE)pOutputData,MAX_PATH,&cbneed,&cbstate))
    {
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        SetLastError(cbstate);
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
              NULL, GetLastError(), NULL,(LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL );
        ::MessageBox(0,(LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf,(WCHAR*)"ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );
        free(pOutputData);
    }

    free(pOutputData);
    ClosePrinter(hXcv);

    return TRUE;

}
```

What i can do to use the XcvData function on my Qt application?

Comment: Try uprading your mingw version or switch to [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) (I recommend the latter as it has better support for the winapi).

Comment: Thanks, i've downloaded tdm64-gcc-4.7.1-3 on this page: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download and using the headers of that it compiles now!